# Move meeting request mail to folder which is not a 'inbox' subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

I set a "run a script" rule for meetings with a specific string in subject.

```vb
Sub AutoDeclineMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass <> "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

Dim oResponse
Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)

End Sub
```

After the decline, I would like to move the mail to another folder (which is not a 'inbox' subfolder) and mark it as read.

I tried with the traditional rules after the "run a script" rule, but it sometimes doesn't run the script but moves to the folder and marks it as read.

How do I make the script decline the meeting, move the mail and mark it as read all together?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Outlook Application class in VBA without creating rules manually. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may consider handling the `ItemAdd` event of the Application class, so you can be aware when an item is dropped to the Inbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

Move the item as the last action in the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()
    AutoDeclineMeetings ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Sub

Sub AutoDeclineMeetings(oRequest As MeetingItem)

If oRequest.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
Set oAppt = oRequest.GetAssociatedAppointment(True)

Dim oResponse
Set oResponse = oAppt.Respond(olMeetingDeclined, True)

oRequest.UnRead = False

' Move is the last action to not loses the reference to oRequest
oRequest.Move Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Test")
End Sub
```